# credit card processing in admin side of an opencart project

Tags: admin, opencart, credit-card

i have a site in opencart, i want to add the ability for the admin user to process an order like a normal front end user.

The admin should be able to enter the credit card details on the admin side under payment options when creating an order and also the credit card should get charged.

Comment: You mean checkout process from admin side? Or the admin user needs to login automatically in frontend if logged on admin side ?

Comment: checkout process from admin side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already a feature of OpenCart (1.5.3 onwards I believe). Go to `SALES > ORDERS` in the admin area, and hit the `INSERT` button, where you'll be able to create your order and have all the necessary options

Assuming you want to do this for the customer yourself, you'll need to log into the customers account using the login feature under `SALES > CUSTOMERS` and then continue as they would

Comment: yes i know that, but there is no option to add credit card details and process the order

Comment: thanks, that was a nice tip, but isnt there an ability to do it through admin side itself ? a plugin or something else ?

Comment: Not that I know of no